# How can I install biopython on anaconda? I tried using "pip install biopython" but it gives me errors

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, biopython

pip install biopython

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'D:\NU\Second' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

With Anaconda always prefer conda over pip:

```
conda install -c anaconda biopython
```

And don't forget to activate your environment before you use it!

Comment: Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: biopython

Comment: What kernel? You have to install it from the Anaconda prompt.